# How to clear select option when user select another option Jquery or Vanilla Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to clear the select option when a different mark is selected,because when I choose another brand don't clear the models from the previous ones. Example I select Mark got models (bmm1,bmw2). I now select Audi I got(audi1,audi2, bmw1,bmw)I don;t need this bmw1 i bmw2 in this option (Audi) mark. I search this question on stackover flow and got any result but structure of code is very different of my.

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#button-getdata').on('change', function() {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=api/reifenmontage/get_marka_data',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#reifenmontage-input select'),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    success: function(json) {

        if (json['success']) {
            for (i in json['success']) {
            var element = json['success'][i];
                //console.log(element);
                html = "\t<option value=\""+ element['model'] + "\">" + 
    element['model'] + "</option>\n";
                $('#result').append(html);  
            }
        }   
    }
});
 });
 </script>  

  <script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
 url: 'index.php?route=api/reifenmontage/mark',
 context: document.body,
 success: function(data) {
  const selectControl = $('#button-getdata');
  selectControl.html(data.map(ExtractData).join(''));
 }
 });

 function ExtractData(item) {
 return ` <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>`;
 }

   </script>
```

and html

```
                 <div id="reifenmontage-input" class="row termin_row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                       <div class="row">
                          <label>Mark und model</label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                       <div class="row">
                          <select name="marka"   class="form-control" 
     id="button-getdata">
                          </select>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                       <div class="row">
                          <select class="form-control" id="result"> 
                          </select> 
                       </div>
                    </div>

                 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="result">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option> <!-- Placeholder -->
</select>
```

Loop your Options and remove them except the first. Because that's your placeholder

```
$("#result option:not(:first)").each(function(){ //Remove all Items but not the first
  $(this).remove();
});

for (i in json['success']) {
  var element = json['success'][i];

  html = "\t<option value=\""+ element['model'] + "\">" + element['model'] + "</option>\n";
  $('#result').append(html);
}
```

More elegant:

```
var optionsArray = [];
$("#result option:not(:first)").each(function(){ //Remove all Items but not the first
  $(this).remove();
});

json['success'].forEach(function(element) { //loop your results
  optionsArray.push(new Option(element.model, element.model)); //create option and store it in array
});

$("#result").append(optionsArray); //append array with options to select
```

Comment: This is work nice. 
Just how to do set empty field mark and model if user no select yet?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Okey but my first option is always selected. Instead that i want  empry field...?

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` appends html to the end of existing html string. Try to use `.html()`. hope this will help you.

update

```
$('#result').append(html);
```

to

```
$('#result').html(html);
```

or if you want to use `append()`function then clear `select` using:

```
$('#result').find('option').remove();
```

Comment: Now my model is underfined

Comment: can you please post what is your success?

Comment: $('#result').html(html);
With this I got only one option in model option...

Comment: collect them in for loop then try to use `html()`

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to delete previous items in your `success` function

See `$('#result').html('')` below

```
success: function(json) {

  if (json['success']) {
        $('#result').html('')
        for (i in json['success']) {
        var element = json['success'][i];
             //console.log(element);
             html = "\t<option value=\""+ element['model'] + "\">" + 
element['model'] + "</option>\n";
             $('#result').append(html);  
        }
  }
```

}